# Why plt.set_xlim is a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I import matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, at some point I try this:

```
plt.set_xlim(datetime.date(2011,1,1),datetime.date(2015,9,1))
```

And as a result I get this:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

My guess was that I, at some point, rewritten `plt.xlim` (or something like that). So, I tried

```
plt.clf()
```

It does not help. I am still getting the same error message. So, does anybody know why `plt.set_xlim` is a list and what to do with that?

Comment: Did you re-use the name `plt` for something else?

Comment: No, but I was (by mistake) executing stuff like `plt.xlim = [d1, d2]` or maybe `plt.set_xlim = [d1, d2]`.

Comment: I cannot restart everything from the scratch, because I am working from IPython notebook and to start everything from the beginning would mean to read the data again and it takes a lot of time (that I do not want to loose).

Comment: `set_xlim` shouldn't be in the namespace of `matplotlib.pyplot` anyway (at least not with my version 1.4.3).  If you've overwritten the `xlim` function which is indeed in the namespace of that module, you can still use the `set_xlim` method of class `matplotlib.pyplot.Axes`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. Apparently the `xlim` must be set by the axis not the plot. <s>This contradicts some of the matplotlib documentation and examples (e.g., [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-invert-axes-py))</s>

Anyways:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(your_xmin, your_xmax)
```

Edit: It appears that the matplotlib documentation has now been fixed.